# Как лучше спросить: "каково", "какое" или "что за"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Этот вопрос родился после дискуссии с автором одного из вопросов по этимологии.
Есть ли разница между тремя следующими вопросами:

- Каково происхождение этого слова?
- Какое происхождение у этого слова?
- Что за происхождение у этого слова?

Если есть разница, то в чем она, все ли вопросы корректны, какой из них предпочтительней? Верно ли, что вопрос «каков?» больше относится к типу предмета, а не к его детальному описанию?

Answer (score 2):

Если говорить только о вопросах, то они различаются степенью строгости стиля (условно): книжный/академический, нейтральный/разговорный, небрежный/панибратский. В последнем случае вопросительное сочетание "что за" несёт в себе элемент междометия: оно часто употребляется в недоуменных вопросах и неодобрительных восклицаниях (вплоть до ругательств). Лучше тот вариант, который подходит к ситуации (от серьёзной лекции до интеллектуальной беседы за кружкой пива).

Вопрос "каков" (без уточняющих оговорок) обычно требует ответа о свойствах в целом (ожидание подробностей не исключается, но начальные сведения важны). *Что вы можете сказать об этом фильме - каков он?* Вопрос "*каково происхождение?*" тоже затрагивает основы предмета.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что "каково" - книжный стиль, "какое" - нейтральный, "что за" - разговорный? Какой из трех перечисленных в моем вопросе вариантов вы бы посоветовали использовать, задавая вопросы по этимологии?